# Redshift duplicate month specification in date/time format

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift, date-format

I'm trying to copy a csv file from S3 into Reshift and I'm hitting this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate month specification in date/time format↵redshiftETL sql="COPY tablename FROM 's3://bucket/keyname.csv' IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/redshift-role' REGION 'us-east-1' CSV TIMEFORMAT AS 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD';"
```

I guess it's thinking `mm` is a duplicate specification of month! Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I've end up using the auto detection of time, now the copy statement looks like:

```
COPY tablename FROM 's3://bucket/keyname.csv'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/redshift-role'
REGION 'us-east-1' CSV
TIMEFORMAT AS 'auto';"
```